# issue with Full-Text-Search Query Execution in Neptune with iam DB authorization enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-neptune

I am trying to integrate ES with neptune for Full-Text-Search Query Execution. With IAM DB authorization enabled in neptune, it is not able to execute query and giving below error

**{"detailedMessage":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.","code":"AccessDeniedException","requestId":"b4bbe6b7-8361-5c9b-1584-ba7a6a64a03c"}**

However with IAM DB authorization disabled, same query execution is working fine.

I am generating AWS SIG4 signature and utilising in the header as part of the query. With IAM enabled , i can able to connect(status check) to neptune DB with same sig4 signature.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have deployed the Neptune integration with Elastic Search, and are trying to run a query that includes a reference to `Neptune#FTS` in the query? Does a query that does not reference `Neptune#  FTS` work? If possible could you expand your question to describe the environment more, describe how you are computing the signature and show an example of the request/query that is failing?

Comment: yes..i have deployed neptune DB with elstic search and any request to neptune DB was failing with above error while IAM is enabled. I used https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-python.html link provided in aws documentation to calculate the signature.

Comment: Issue is fixed now. the issue was within aws sig4 generation provided in the aws documentation python link. I have done few enhancement to  the python script with explicitly setting "Host" with neptune DB endpoint in the request header section which resolved proper aws sig4 generation and i can able to query neptune DB as well elastic search with neptune  IAM DB authorization.